# How can I send forms that get constructed dynamically to javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm displaying rows from my database as a table, and each row is a separate form that's constructed dynamically. The forms can be identified by the row's primary key, id. I would like to be able to send the respective form to javascript and access the values, but can't figure out how.

This is using .erb

```
<% thresholds.each do |threshold| %>
<form name = "threshold<%= threshold["id"]%>">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="score" value="<%= threshold["score"] %>" size="1">
    </td>  
    <td>
        <button onClick="saveThreshold(this.form)">Save</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="deleteThreshold">Delete</button>
    </td>
</form>
<% end %>
```

Javascript:

```
function saveThreshold(form) {
    alert('my score is: ' + form.score.value);
}
```

but it says form is undefined.

Comment: You need to reference the form (maybe document.getelementbyId?). Your parameter won't be injected for you.

Comment: A button has a default type of `submit`, so if you don't want to submit the form whenever a button is clicked, change it's type -> `<button type="button" id="deleteThreshold">Delete</button>`

Comment: Get target of click event and go through parent nodes of the target element to find element with tagName 'form'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector this.form is not the correct way to access the form element from the DOM. Try:

```
<% thresholds.each do |threshold| %>
<form name="threshold<%= threshold["id"]%>">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="score" value="<%= threshold["score"] %>" size="1">
    </td>  
    <td>
        <button onClick="saveThreshold(threshold<%= threshold["id"]%)">Save</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="deleteThreshold">Delete</button>
    </td>
</form>
<% end %>
```

That way you are getting the value via the forms name attribute instead of this.form